# Package an existing Ubuntu installation into an ISO image

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image

How would you pack a current installation of Linux to a bootable ISO image?

What I'm trying to do is have my current Ubuntu installation on a DVD and whenever I'm using a different computer, I could boot from the DVD and have my whole environment already there.

Comment: Recognize that you would need a rewritable DVD to have anything other than a LiveDVD session (transient session).  An option is to save it to a flash drive, which you could use as a fully functional OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Remastersys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys). It does exactly what you want and the two times I tried it, I did not bump into any issues